# How to get all the pod details using CLI for any given region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, kubectl

As part of my work, I need to get all the pods details for any given region.

I normally get the pod details by running *kubectl get pods -n <my_name_space>*. But now, I need to get the pod details for any given region. Is there any option to do that?

From the AWS UI (web) I can see them by changing the region manually but looking for automation.
[image]

I have tried with aws-cli as well. But, I could not find any option to do that. Any suggestion?

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to fetch the nodes as that's the only thing region tagged and then find the pods deployed on those nodes.

Comment: I guesss you can do somethinglike this
1. list the clusters in region (aws eks list-clusters --region us-east-1),     2. describe the cluster (aws eks describe-cluster --name <cluster_name>)       3. grep arn value and use it as context in kubectl cmd (kubectl get pods --context arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:123123123123123:cluster/cluster_name)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Does kubectl works across region?

[]/home/ec2-user:$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --context arn:aws:eks:eu-west-2:XXXX:cluster/london-eks-cluster

Is working fine for me. Please note that my .kube/config is pointing to london cluster. But, when I tried with another region, I am getting the following error

Comment: []:/home/ec2-user:$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --context arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:XXXX:cluster/singapore-eks-cluster
Error in configuration: context was not found for specified context: arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:XXXX:cluster/singapore-eks-cluster
[]:/home/ec2-user:$

Comment: @jordanm, is there any CLI way to fetch the nodes for a given region?

Comment: @dgm then follow this: Make Region as parameter
1. First run this command to get list of all clusters(aws eks list-clusters --region us-east-1) 2. Pass the cluster name along with region to this command (aws eks --region us-east-1 update-kubeconfig --name <Cluster_Name>), 3. Then run this cmd to list all the pods (kubectl get pods -A)

Comment: @jordanm its difficult to get nodename. First have to list nodegroups in a region, then describe the nodesgreoups to fetch autoscalingname, describe autoscaling name to fetch nodename, then list all pods with grep of nodename.